# Android jelly bean - no makefile found

Tags: android, android-source

This probably must be a very stupid question, but I am new to AOSP programming.

When I build the platform using ". `build/envsetup.sh"` and `"lunch"` commands as specified on the website, it runs perfectly. But when I type in `"make" or "m"`, it gives me the following error

**'make: ******** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.'*

Am I missing any files here? If yes, then where can I find those. And I really don't want to go through that repo stuff again, its too exhausting.. And all my directories have .mk files.

**What file is it asking for?**

Comment: Check if `Makefile` is present inside android directory (`android/Makefile`).

Comment: No. Its not there. Where can I get it?

Comment: It should have sync when you have called `$ repo sync` probably if you are following [downloading android source code](https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html). I think re-sync might solve the Issue but not sure.

Comment: I just want that file. re-sync is taking a lot of time. Is there any other way?

Comment: I'm not sure but you can take a look at [using-repo](http://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html).

Comment: Still no luck !! It does not have a separate file called Makefile..

Comment: A run of `repo sync` will be very quick since your workspace should be quite up to date. It's the `<copyfile src="core/root.mk" dest="Makefile" />` line in .repo/manifest.xml that causes the file to be created by copying core/root.mk. You could copy that file by hand, but chances are this isn't the only problem with your workspace.

Comment: The error is also mentioning "No Targets Specified". What lunch target are you specifying?

Comment: It gives a list after the lunch command. So I choose from there.

Comment: @user3345681 aaand what are you choosing?